# How does textBaseline in canvas works?

Tags: javascript, html, text, canvas

I have this simple code: http://codepen.io/hypertornado/pen/rIbsH where are two lines of text drawn on canvas. How is it possible, that there is an empty space between top canvas border and first letter (█) at first line and there is no empty space between first letters at each lines?

```
canvas = window.document.getElementById("canvas")
context = canvas.getContext('2d')
context.fillStyle = "rgba(100,150, 0,1)"
context.textBaseline = 'alphabetic'
context.font = "30px Arial"
context.fillText("█hello", 0, 30)
context.fillText("█hello", 0, 60)
```

Tested on Google Chrome on Mac OS X.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing textBaseline to bottom

```
context.textBaseline = 'bottom'
```

More info here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Drawing_text_using_a_canvas

Comment: Thanks, but it did not help, still the same.

Comment: I forked your example here http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BFpdz , wasn't that your desired result ?